# Making requests with StreamWriter to Retrieve/Send JSON Data

Tags: c#, proxy, streamwriter, socks

I am trying to create a Code that will wend WebRequests via a SOCKS proxy, so far I succeeded in connecting, or hitting a website through this SOCKS-proxy.
The problem really is the way these requests are handled.
I want to send a GET request and retrieve JSON data from an API, if possible even send data to an API.

### Request Code:

```
try
{
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
     {
         writer.Write("GET / HTTP/1.0 host: <link to API> \r\n\r\n");
         writer.Flush();
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
         {
              Char[] readBuff = new Char[256];
              int count = reader.Read(readBuff, 0, 256);
              Console.WriteLine("\n contents:\n ");
              while (count > 0)
              {
                  String outputData = new String(readBuff, 0, count);
                  Console.WriteLine(outputData);
                  count = reader.Read(readBuff, 0, 256);
              }
         }
      }
}

catch (Exception e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

No please understand that for my own reasons I am obligated to go through a SOCKS-Proxy, but there is NO issue there. I Am able to send the request. I am getting an answer!! I'm just not getting the right answer.

### Response:

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using the *actual* `WebRequest` type (or `HttpClient` or `WebClient`)? I don't see why you'd want to write your own HTTP client code...

Comment: you might need a content-type header of application/json to tell the server you want json data instead of html.

Comment: I speculate he is using `WebRequest`s, but only because of his title.

Comment: @JonSkeet Because I'm using a SOCKS-Proxy I need to write a stream with a http-request to it.

Comment: @LewisTaylor I have tried to add this, but it won't work. Or I must have incorrectly added it. How do you think I should add this header?

Comment: I would expect the existing APIs to handle SOCKS proxies easily.

Comment: could you answer either of these two questions: 1. If I were to use HttpClient or WebClient, what would the code look like, assuming I already established connection to the SOCKS-proxy? OR 2. Can you see any error in my HTTP client-code as it is now? What is causing this error, how do I fix it?